# Наследование значений С++

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, конструктор

Я не совсем понимаю как работает наследование.

```
class A {
 protected:
  int num1;
 public:
  A(int num1) {
   this->num1=num1;
  }
};

class B : public A {
 protected:
  int num2;
 public:
  B(int num2) {
   this->num2=num2;
  } 
};

int main() {
 A a(5);
 B b(4);
return 0;
}
```

В объекте `b` есть переменная `num1`. Она пустая или нет? Поля наследуются, а значения в этия полях? Есть ли способ унаследовать значение `num1` объекта `a`  в `b`?

Comment: Что такое "пустая переменная"? Переменная не бывает пустой.

Comment: Ну вот не надо придираться) Вопрос другой.

Comment: Вопрос совершенно не ясен. Вы вообще не назначаете никакие значения никаким переменным. О наследовании каких "значений" идёт речь?

Comment: Можно ли из обьекта В получить значение num1 обьекта А?

Comment: Получить то можно. Но `A` - это класс, а не объект. У класса нет никаких значений. Значения есть у экземпляров `A`. У каждого экземпляра `A` свойе `num1`.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала ваш код не скомпилируется - потому что у вас нет конструктора по умолчанию `A`. Так что вы просто вынуждены написать что-то типа

```
B(int num2):A(0) {
    this->num2;   // Что за бред?
}
```

или

```
B(int num1, int num2):A(num1) {
    this->num2;   // Что за бред?
}
```

и тем самым инициализировать обе переменные...

Кстати, правильнее записать:

```
B(int num1, int num2):A(num1),num2(num2) {}
```

Конструктор наследника всегда вызывает конструктор родителя, даже если вы его не указываете явно (в этом случае вызывается конструктор по умолчанию), что и является, как мне кажется, ответом на ваш вопрос...

Ну, а обратиться к `num1` в классе `B` вполне можно - раз уж вы объявили ее `protected`. Но только *внутри класса* - т.е. *внутри функций класса `B`*. Просто как к `num1` (ну, или `this->num1` при необходимости).

Comment: А в смысле this->num2 "бред" ?

Comment: Ну напишите вместо этого `2;` - эффект тот же. Это строка, которая **ничего не делает**.

Comment: Точно. Правильно this->num2=num2

Comment: Можно и так. Но с *формальной* точки зрения это не инициализация, а присваивание. И если `num2` - объект какого-то класса, то будет отдельно выполнена инициализация (конструирование), и отдельно - присваивание...

Comment: К заминусовавшему: хотелось бы понять, что именно в моем ответе неверно - почему стоит минус?..

Comment: Это не я) Буду вечером разбираться с вашим решением.

Comment: Я и написал - "К заминусовавшему", а не к вам :)

Answer (score 0):

Наследование только копирует структуру данных базового класса. Если вы хотите взять значения из другого объекта, то передавайте ссылку откуда. И чтобы копировать эти данные нужно добавить конструктор копирования.

```
class A {
 protected:
  int num1;
 public:
  A(int num1) {
   this->num1=num1;  }
  A(A const & a):num1(a.num1){}
};

class B : public A {
 protected:
  int num2;
 public:
  B(A const & a , int num2):A(a) {
   this->num2=num2;  }
};
int main() {
 A a(5);
 B b(a,4);
return 0;
}
```